# Select #... in an object with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Felix Brun's js library for Last Fm's API, however when fetching data I get an object in return. As expected. But I want to use the artist's name in a div with query like this `$(selector).html(data.recenttracks.track[0].artist.{what should be here})`

But his or her name is under the #text key. How do I select that in the code above? When trying `data.recenttracks.track[0].artist.#text` the console errors that # is a illegal character. Here's the structure of that last bit: [image]

Comment: You can also access it like this: `data.recenttracks.track[0].artist['#text']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using indexer instead:

```
data.recenttracks.track[0].artist['#text']
```